# Error decoding string json in flutter, "type String is not subtype of type Map"

Tags: json, string, rest, flutter, parsing

again with some doubts in flutter, I need to decode a json that I receive from an api, but it gives me a conversion error, it is because the json comes as a deserialized string, some way to solve this detail. Thank you very much for the help.

```
String strVar = "{ \"status\": \"1\", \"message\": \"test\",
                    \"cars\": [ { \"carId\": \"1\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, 
                                    { \"carId\": \"2\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, 
                                    { \"businessId\": \"3\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }
                                   ] }"

//Here error
Map<String,dynamic> mapAPI = json.decode(strVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use multi-line string literals, encase the string in triple quotations `'''`, or use only one line.

**Single-line**

```
String strVar = "{ \"status\": \"1\", \"message\": \"test\",\"cars\": [ { \"carId\":\"1\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, { \"carId\": \"2\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, { \"businessId\": \"3\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }] }";
  
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(strVar);
  
print(map);
```

**Multi-line**

```
String strVar = '''{ \"status\": \"1\", \"message\": \"test\",
                    \"cars\": [ { \"carId\": \"1\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, 
                                    { \"carId\": \"2\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }, 
                                    { \"businessId\": \"3\", \"carName\": \"Car N°1\" }
                                   ] }'''; // String encased in 3 single-quotations at start and end

Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(strVar);

print(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is only in example mode, the string is a single line, the problem that I cannot deserialize.

Comment: Solved, calling json.decode twice, it worked, it would be like this: json.decode (json.decode (strVar)).

In case it works for someone, and thanks for all your help.